# Можно ли получить имя переменной, которая содержит список?

Tags: python-3.x

хочу узнать можно ли узнать имя переменной, которая содержит список?

Есть допустим list = [1, 2, 3], и я хочу узнать через команду print имя переменной list не вводя при этом print('list'), так как каким образом назван список я не знаю.
Пример:

```
num1 = [1, 2, 3]
num2 = [1, 23, 3]
num3 = [13, 2, 3]
node = [num1, num2, num3]
print(str(num1))

результат:   \[1, 2, 3]/
```

Имею 3 списка и они помещены в еще один список. При попытке достать имя списка через str() выводиться соответственно содержимое списка-в списке, а хотелось бы имя.
Если в списке группа то выводит

Спасибо

Comment: Ты хочешь получить названия переменной num1?
Если да, то print(str(node[0]))

Comment: Никак. Используйте словарь, где ключ - имя, значение - подсписок.

Comment: @huskey, если сделать print(str(node[0])) выведет [1, 2, 3], а нужно num1 получить

Comment: @insolor, да похоже придется создавать список имен списков, параллельно. Спасибо

Comment: Сделал таким образом
    lists = [[natives, 'Natives'], [leaders, 'Leaders'], [eats, 'Eats']]